# "The YouTube API Services quota has been further reduced" に返信後、３か月連絡なし。

Tags: youtube-data-api

クオータを減らされて、仕事に支障が出ております。
対応策をご存知な方がいらっしゃれば教えて貰えますか？

Comment: このわかりにくさは全くあなたの責任ではないのですが、「Stack Overflow」「stackoverflow.com」とここはほぼ別のサービスだと思ってください。ここに投稿されてもヘルプに書かれているようにGoogleのエンジニアはウオッチしていません。

Answer (score 1):

そもそも何に何を返信したのかわからないため、誰にも何も分かりません。

「返信」とありますので、*想像ですが*、Googleから「YouTube APIのクォータを減らすよ」というメールが送られて来て、それに「嫌だ、増やせ」と返信したということでしょうか？そのメールには「返信すれば、減らしたクォータを増やすよ、3ヶ月以内に連絡するよ」と書いてありましたか？もし、書いていない場合は、返信しても無視されるだけです。

Googleを含め、インターネット上のサービスが送る自動送信メールのほとんどは、送信専用の返信を受け付けていません。原則、返信しても無視されます(読まれること無く捨てられます)。送られた側からの問い合わせに備えて、メールとは別の問い合わせ用のフォームの案内や問い合わせ先の電話番号・メールアドレスがメール内に記載されています。まずは、メールを確認して、どこに何をしなければならないのかを確認してください。「問い合わせはこのメールに返信しろ」と書いていない限り、返信しても無駄です。

もし、返信しろと書いてあった場合、題名や本文内にissue番号(記号の場合もある)が含まれているはずです。この番号が題名などに無い場合は、一体何の問題に対する返信かわからないため、同じく捨てられます。以前Google Workspaceに関する問い合わせでサポートとメールのやり取りをしたとことがありましたが、サポートからのメールには`#`から始まる8桁の数字が必ず題名についていました。もし、返信時にこれらの番号を消してしまうと、スパム扱いで捨てられてしまう可能性があります。返信する場合は「題名を変えない(Re:がつくだけ)」かつ「本文の引用部分はそのまま」にするようにしてください。